# How can I use jsf ui:repeat inside af:column for a list per table entry?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, oracle-adf, uirepeat

I would like to display a list of information per entry in the table. For example for each user, one can have multiple cell phone numbers.

The users are listed in the  and I have an  for the cell numbers. I would like to loop through the list of numbers per user and list them in the column for the cell phone numbers.

I have tried to add the ui:repeat in the  in the following way:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{user.cellNumbers}" var="cellNumber">
```

and the table holds the user array in the following manner:

```
<af:table id="t1-rapb" value="#{userBean.users}" var="user">
```

I expected the ui:repeat to iterate through the list of numbers per user, but instead nothing appears in that column. What am I missing in order to make this work?

Comment: I don't see a `af:column` anywhere so it is unclear to see how you (try to) use this

Comment: Hi, thank you for your efforts. It was a simple misunderstanding that occurred. ui:repeat is working correctly now

Comment: ok, then please remove the question...